# How to integrate partial exponentials?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x^{5/2}(x+1)^{7/2}}}$$

I have tried taking the whole thing to the power 1/3 and then multiplying it inside the bracket, but I am unable to reach anywhere. How to proceed with such questions?

Comment: please don't use images type it in  latex

Comment: @user568101 Here's [a guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on MathJax. In particular, you can write integrals as \$\int \$, and powers as \$x^{5/2} \$.

Comment: @TobyMak  will do

Answer (score 0):

Raise both terms in the denominator to the $1/3$ power, then you have an integral of the form $\int {1 \over f(x) g(x)}\ dx$.  Continue using integration by parts, where the functions are $u'(x) = 1/f(x)$ and $v(x) = 1/g(x)$ of the form $\int u'(x) v(x)\ dx$ where the $u'(x)$ is solved by an integral $u(x) v(x) - \int v'(x) u(x)\ dx$.

So here:  $u'(x) = 1/x^{5/6} = x^{-5/6}$ so $u(x) = 6 x^{1/6}$ and $v(x) = 1/(1+x)^{7/6}$.  Next use the general formula for integration by parts:

The first term is $u(x)v(x) = 6 x^{1/6}/(x+1)^{7/2}$.  The second term is $\int u(x) v'(x)\ dx = \int 6 x^{1/6} v'(x)\ dx$, where $v'(x) = -\frac{7}{6 (x+1)^{13/6}}$.  Then substitute into this last integral.

$$\frac{6 x (x+1)}{\sqrt[3]{x^{5/2} (x+1)^{7/2}}}$$

Comment: The OP can easily find that out using Wolfram Alpha. Are you going to say anything more?

Comment: Where did that 6x(x+1) come form?

Comment: @TobyMak: Can the OP do so easily? The OP has given no indication of such ability, nor of any inclination to do so.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I find it frustrating when you change your answer every few seconds. I would like to offer some feedback, but I find it hard to do when the content always changes.

Comment: @Hurkyl I wrote this comment when the answer only was a single formula. I have no reason to take it down once the answer changes.

Comment: I urge you to wait for more than two minutes while I write MathJax and then post to ensure the mathematical typesetting is correct.  (One cannot see it while writing... at least not on my browser.)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork OK, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork is that the final answer you wrote up there?

Answer (score 0):

The integrand is $x^{-5/6}(x+1)^{-7/6}$. After shamelessly cheating with WA, we investigate a solution of the form

$$x^\alpha(x+1)^\beta$$ that gives the derivative

$$(\alpha x+\alpha+\beta x)x^{\alpha-1}(x+1)^{\beta-1}.$$

We can try to make the first factor proportional to $1$, to $x$ or to $x+1$. Then with $\alpha+\beta=0$, we have $\alpha=\frac16$ and $\beta=-\frac16$ that fit by magic.

Comment: I must admit I found no straight way to solve, without a hint.